# Shell session variable does not assign value

Tags: variables, sh, aix

I'm trying to figure out why the variable does not store the value of below command in the dev environment (AIX 6.1):

```
> DBSIZE=`db2 "CALL GET_DBSIZE_INFO(?, ?, ?, 0)" | grep -p DATABASESIZE
> | grep Value | cut -c21-`
```

If I execute `echo $DBSIZE` it retrieves blank, without any value.

However, when I run only the command

```
db2 "CALL GET_DBSIZE_INFO(?, ?, ?, 0)" | grep -p DATABASESIZE | grep Value | cut -c21-
```

it retrieves the value.

Also, I executed the same in prod environment (AIX 6.1 also) and it works fine!

Any clue??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell you what the *exact* problem is but, if you break it down into sections, you'll at least be able to identify where it's going wrong:

```
DBSIZE=`db2 "CALL GET_DBSIZE_INFO(?, ?, ?, 0)"`
echo "$DBSIZE"
DBSIZE=`db2 "CALL GET_DBSIZE_INFO(?, ?, ?, 0)" | grep -p DATABASESIZE`
echo "$DBSIZE"
DBSIZE=`db2 "CALL GET_DBSIZE_INFO(?, ?, ?, 0)" | grep -p DATABASESIZE | grep Value`
echo "$DBSIZE"
```

and so on.

One thing you *may* want to try (if that command is truly split across lines as shown) is to put in on one line. I seem to remember that some shells have trouble with embedded newlines inside backtick commands. If the first line can be seen as a complete command, it will sometimes treat it as two separate commands and the one starting with `|` will cause a problem.

Comment: I proceeded the same way you suggested me, and the variable stuck on the first pipe `|`. The value of `GET_DBSIZE_INFO` procedure is shown, but after filtering using `| grep -p`, the variable shows nothing again.

The strange is that doing the same on both environments (same OS), it works only in one.